# Installing ssl certificates in GlassFish v3

Tags: glassfish, ssl-certificate, glassfish-3

I have just installed a new ssl certificate on GlassFish 3. I also changed all references to s1as to a new certificate alias in config/domain.xml. Everything seems to work fine, but I wonder if I have to change all "s1as" entries in

config/sun-acc.xml, wss-server-config-1.0.xml,wss-server-config-2.0.xml as well ? Do settings in these files affect anything ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you did not use

```
keytool -delete -alias s1as -keystore
```

and

```
keytool <opts> -keystore keystore.jks -validity <val_days> -alias s1as
```

instead?
sun-acc xml comes in to play while accessing EJB objects that are residing in a remote system

Bottomline is:
You would require to edit sun-acc.xml and other configs that refer to si1as

Comment: A brief description of what those commands actually do would be nice!